# Knockout Js binding to an edit modal with an undo feature

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using ko.js to display a table of venues.

Each venue has an edit button that brings up a dialog showing the editable data.

When the edit button is pressed I bind the venue to the dialog and I store a copy of the data in an undo object.

When I edit fields on the dialog, both the dialog and table are updated.

When I cancel the edit, I bind the venue to the undo objects state. This updates the dialog but it does not update on the table.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Here is my view model.

```
VenueViewModel = function(venues) {
    var self = this;

    var venueModal = $("#venueModal");
    this.venues = ko.mapping.fromJS(venues);
    this.venue = ko.observable();
    this.venueUndo = null;

    //Cancel an edit                
    this.cancel = function() {
        self.venue(ko.mapping.fromJS(self.venueUndo));
        venueModal.modal("hide");
    }

    //Edit an existing venue
    this.edit = function(venue) {
        self.venue(venue);
        self.venueUndo = ko.mapping.toJS(venue);
        venueModal.modal("show");
    };

    //Create a new venue
    this.create = function() {
        self.venue(new Venue());
        venueModal.modal("show");
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new VenueViewModel(venues));
```

Comment: You will need to have an explicit Save where you update the item in the table: http://jsfiddle.net/JHzQ3/ you should also check this article: http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article nemesv linked in his comment was the answer.

http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [KO-UndoManager](https://github.com/bago/knockout-undomanager) for this. Here's a sample code to register your viewmodel:

```
VenueViewModel.undoMgr = ko.undoManager(VenueViewModel, {
  levels: 12,
  undoLabel: "Undo (#COUNT#)",
  redoLabel: "Redo"
});
```

You can then add undo/redo buttons in your html as follows:

```
 <div class="row center-block">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="
      click: undoMgr.undoCommand.execute, 
      text: undoMgr.undoCommand.name, 
      css: { disabled: !undoMgr.undoCommand.enabled() }">UNDO</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="
      click: undoMgr.redoCommand.execute, 
      text: undoMgr.redoCommand.name, 
      css: { disabled: !undoMgr.redoCommand.enabled() }">REDO</button>
  </div>
```

And [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nB2129?p=preview)'s a Plunkr showing it in action.

Answer (score 0):

You set Knockout observables like this:

```
self.venue(ko.mapping.fromJS(self.venueUndo));
```

Comment: This fixes the binding in the dialog but not the original table as well. When I edit in the dialog it also updated the venues table. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

We Have a small extension to Knockout.js as part out project that extends observables so they can be registered to different stacks of there history.

Maybe it can help you.

[Knockout-Memento](https://github.com/mmjr/Knockout-Memento)

Comment: I checked out this library and it looks very cool, but I had some trouble running the examples. Can I contact you somewhere with questions?